# Unable To Format Infected Pendrive Write Protected

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive

My 16 GB HP pendrive  is write protected ( we didn't do it! ) by some trojan/virus that infected in it. My McAfee AV is detecting the trojan but can't do anything about it since the pen drive is write protected.

I have searched and tried all the immediate solutions found on internet, editing the registry and trying various USB format tools but none of them worked.

Is there any way I can format and recover the pendrive?

I am using Windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: What methods exactly have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried editing registry value in StorageDevicePolicy, USB restore tool and DISKPART method on command prompt, nine of them worked...is there no way to remove such virus from pendrive?

Comment: Virus code on a pen-drive cannot write-protect the drive unless you execute the code. If you did that then your machine is infected, but McAfee should have protected you from executing virus code. If you're not infected, there must another reason why your drive is write-protected. Some drives have a hardware switch.

Comment: You don't even indicate what is being detected.  If you are trying to do this within Windows that's likely your problem (if the lock is caused by software that is)

Comment: @AFH actually it is my friend's pen drive. She got this virus infected from another friend's computer.She asked for my help for fixing this issue and when I plug it in to my PC, mcafee is detecting trojans but it can't delete them since the pen drive is write protected.

Comment: @Ramhound No, this is not Windows problem, it is saying same error when I tried to format in another pc.

Comment: @Suchit - You cannot rule out a Windows problem.  I wouldn't at the very least, I would try a Linux tool, and wipe the drive that way.  But I would agree with AFH, the virus didn't write protect the drive, this is likely a hardware lock.

Comment: @Ramhound i guess linux is the only option left.

Comment: @Ramhound this pendrive has no hardware lock, looking on internet it seems nobody has ever found solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the USB drive is just busted, and that the infection isn't doing anything to cause the write-protection.

Download, burn and boot to a [GPartEd](http://gparted.org/) disk (it's Linux-based) and try to remove the partition(s) on the drive, if it still thinks it's write protected when GPartEd tried to access it, then the drive is broken IMO.

Comment: i will try using linux to format.

Comment: tried using linux, this is what gparted shows [image] (https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-zqIPfKAP2SQ/VBzmA_E1tkI/AAAAAAAAFpc/bnAqDa16fvs/s1600/WP_20140920_001.jpg)